# Rename All Files in directory and subdirectories Linux

Tags: linux, mv

I've searched many times in other Questions and i did not finded the answer ,

I need to rename a part of file names in a folder and all of subdirectories on that folder .

I've found the right CMD , but it just works for files in current dir , how can i use this for Rename fiels in all sub directories too ?

```
for filename in *mohsen*; do echo mv \"$filename\" \"${filename//mohsen/bar}\"; done | /bin/bash
```

THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a tool like [`mmv`](http://mylinuxbook.com/mmv-a-command-line-utility-to-move-copy-link-append-multiple-files-easily/) to achieve that, or a more modern, nicer way would be to use [`pythonpy`](https://github.com/Russell91/pythonpy):

```
% find -regex '.*mohsen.*' | py -x '"mv `{}` `{}`".format(x,re.sub("mohsen", "foo", x)' | sh
```

---

as you say you cannot use python (WTF?!?!?), here's another option:

something like:

```
for filename in $(find -regex '.*mohsen.*'); do echo mv \"$filename\" \"${filename//mohsen/bar}\"; done | /bin/bash
```

but that will fail with files that have spaces, so you might need to use:

```
OLDIFS="$IFS" IFS=$'\n' for filename in $(find -regex '.*mohsen.*'); do echo mv \"$filename\" \"${filename//mohsen/bar}\"; done | /bin/bash; IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

in order to setup line delimiters to only the carriage return and not the spaces. Beware that's an ugly non-recommended option to do it, which is fine for a "one time" use, but don't use that in a script.

Also, once you're happy with the output using "echo" in the commands I gave, remove the echo and run it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , but i haven't python or mmv on this machine and i can't install anything else . I've limited access i just can use basic centos installed tools

Comment: you haven't python on a basic centos?! I cannot believe that a distribution less than 10 years old doesn't have it! `easy_install pythonpy` should work on any system, even on a good old debian squeeze (and even maybe a debian potato)!

Comment: Thank you , it works Greatt :D yes , i don't know what was changed this server admin before ! see : [ahil@server111 1]# whereis python
python:
[ahil@server111 1]# python -V
-bash: python: command not found